# Excluding files from git-diff

Tags: git

I am tracking a project with git. There are some Xcode project files in the working copy that I want to keep tracking, but do not want to see in diffs, because there are always dozens of changed lines that I am never interested in. Is there a simple way to have `git-diff` skip these files? I’ve tried to set up a custom “silent” diff tool:

```
$ cat .gitattributes 
Project.xcodeproj/* diff=nodiff

$ cat ~/.gitconfig 
[diff "nodiff"]
    command = /bin/true
```

But:

```
$ git diff
external diff died, stopping at Project.xcodeproj/zoul.mode1v3.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

The problem is that `/bin/true` will return immediately without reading its input. `git diff` therefore thinks, quite reasonably, that it has died prematurely.

What you really want to do is to unset the diff attribute, not set it to a bogus command. Try this in your `.gitattributes`:

```
Project.xcodeproj/* -diff
```

Comment: Excluding the whole directory didn't work for me, because many of the files are in deeper subdirs. Instead *.xcuserstate -diff was helpful to ignore the often changing file.

Comment: @Bemmu: To be fair, I was only using the same pattern as in the question. There wasn't any suggestion that the pattern wasn't working in the original askers situation.

Comment: Sure, just wanted to include this since it might help whoever is reading this to solve their situation.

Comment: A lot of similar questions on SO, couldn't find an answer as simple and effective as this!

Comment: I'm using Git 1.9.4 and adding `-diff` now makes diff process the files I want to exclude as binary files, instead of ignoring them...

Comment: If you want to exclude subdirectories as well, make it `Project.xcodeproj/**/* -diff` instead.

Comment: Also does not prevent external diff from processing it (may partly be because it only treats it as binary now instead of ignoring)

Comment: @StevenLu You can fix this by patching your git-difftool--helper, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7674147/2448947

Comment: Note that `.gitattributes` goes in your project directory with `.gitignore`, NOT in your home directory with `.gitconfig`

Comment: This recipe does not help for `git difftool`, while the recipe with `\bin\true` does help.

Answer (score 7):

You may use an alias in your .git/config

```
[alias]
        mydiff = !git diff | filterdiff -x "*/Project.xcodeproj/*"
```

You need filterdiff (from patchutils) for this trick.

```
sudo apt-get install patchutils
```

Still the diff isn't perfect, it leaves some garbage :

```
yannick@yannick-desktop:~/git-filter-test$ git mydiff
diff --git a/Project.xcodeproj/dummy.txt b/Project.xcodeproj/dummy.txt
index 3e1f9e6..89dfed9 100644
diff --git a/dummy2.txt b/dummy2.txt
index 91966ce..d9588a9 100644
--- a/titi.txt
+++ b/titi.txt
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
 aaaaaaaaaa
-bbbbbbbbb
 cccccc
+ddd
```

Comment: This is very nice, thank you. The garbage is just fine, at least I know those files changed. But I lose the coloring, is there a way to get it back? I tried git diff --color to force it, but then filterdiff gets confused by the color escapes and stops filtering.

Comment: Oh yes, | colordiff | less -r.

Comment: Thanks for answers to this question -- filterdiff is nearly meeting my needs -- however, the "garbage" remaining is causing me trouble -- is there a way to say "completely remove all reference to a file" using filterdiff?

Answer (score 7):

Another solution that produces clean output without any external tools (add to `.git/config`):

```
[alias]
    mydiff = !git diff -- $(git diff --name-only | grep -Ev "Project.xcodeproj/")
```

Then run it with:

```
git mydiff
```

Note that `git diff --name-only` is better than `git ls-files` because it will pass a shorter list of files to `git diff`, since only files that are modified will be included. I've run into trouble with exceeding the maximum number of arguments in large projects when using `git ls-files`.

Comment: I ran into issues with complex paths with this. I suspect it would better if you used the -z switch: "do not munge pathnames and use NULs as output field terminators".

Answer (score 1):

Just incase someone else has the same pain we had.
We wanted to exclude a file that had already been committed.

This post was way more useful:
[working with .git/info/exclude too late](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158857/working-with-git-info-exclude-too-late)

Specifically what you need to ignore a file is actually use the command git remove
See **git rm** (http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rm.html)

you test it by going

**`git rm --dry-run *.log`**
(if you say wanted to exclude all the log files)

this will output what *would be* excluded if you ran it.

then

you run it by going

**`git rm *.log`**
(or whatever filename path / expression you want to)