# Why is .gitignore not including a file prefixed by a !

Tags: git, include, gitignore

My .gitignore file reads as follows:

```
build/
glucosia.xcodeproj/
!glucosia.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
core-plot/framework/build
core-plot/framework/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj/
!core-plot/framework/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
.DS_Store
Classes/.DS_Store
```

Strangely, `glucosia.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` is not ignored, as I would expect.

But, `core-plot/framework/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` is still being ignored.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `glucosia.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` by any chance already part of the repository?

Comment: glucosia.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj is already tracked, but 
core-plot/framework/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj is not. My solution is to add the second file to the repo. So, it seems that the ! notation only applies to tracked files. This wasn't clear from the docs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the [`gitignore` man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub//software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html):

> A `gitignore` file specifies intentionally untracked files that git should ignore

If `glucosia.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` (as suggested by [Alan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/66353/alan-haggai-alavi) in the comments) is already tracked, you need to remove it from the cache, and then the gitingore directive will take effect.

```
git rm --cached glucosia.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
```

If the file was already committed, see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158857/working-with-git-info-exclude-too-late) (`git commit --amend` to remove it from the latest commit)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, but a different solution.  If you ignore a directory but not a file within it, it will not work.  You have to ignore a directory's **files**.

#### This doesn't work:

```
conf/
!conf/config.json.orig
```

#### This will work:

```
conf/*
!conf/config.json.orig
```

Comment: I've got a similar issue but the directory I'm ignoring has several layers in it and the file I want to un-ignore is a few layers deep. My .gitignore looks something like this:
    src/sys
    !src/sys/lib/perl5/myLib.pm