# git status shows a file that I have listed explicitly in my .gitignore file

Tags: git

I have the following line in my .gitignore file:

```
var/www/docs/.backroom/billing_info/inv.pl
```

but when I type 'git status' I am told the following:

```
#   modified:   var/www/docs/.backroom/billing_info/inv.pl
```

I dont understand how a file which is explicitly listed as an ignore pattern could be listed as modified when I want git to ignore it.

There are no lines starting with a ! in my .gitignore file

Here is my entire .gitignore file for reference: http://pastebin.com/Jw445Qd7

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That should only happen if `inv.pl` is already tracked (see [`gitignore` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore.html)).

Try (with [`git rm`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm)) a:

```
git rm --cached var/www/docs/.backroom/billing_info/inv.pl
```

If the file is already committed, see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158857/working-with-git-info-exclude-too-late).

Comment: According to the manual, you should use --cached instead of --cache :)

Comment: @Johanneke Thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly, and added a link to the documentation.