# Github. How do I make changes to what is ignored via .gitignore?

Tags: xcode, git, github

I have an Xcode project that uses git for version control. I have a .gitignore file to ignore the build subdirectory:

build/*

I recently added a subdirectory that contains an Xcode project and forgot to update the .gitignore file before checking it in.

Is there any way to make git ignore the build subdirctory now, after the fact?

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 git rm --cached dirToignore
 echo dirToignore >>.gitignore
```

From there, a new commit will record that:

- `dirToignore` is no longer par of versioned data
- `dirToIgnore` won't show up anymore in `git status`

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107701/how-can-i-remove-ds-store-files-from-a-git-repository) for similar advices.
If you want to amend previous commit in order to remove said subdirectory from an old commit, see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158857/working-with-git-info-exclude-too-late):

```
 git commit --amend
```

can help you remove it from at least the last commit.