# Specifying dir/* in .gitattributes doesn't suppress all the desired output

Tags: git

I want to suppress all the output for files in

```
    dir/*
```

when using the command

```
    git diff
```

I decided to follow the suggestions from
[Excluding files from git-diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016798/excluding-files-from-git-diff)

**Method 1.**

Adding to **.git/config**

```
[alias]
    mydiff = !git diff -- $(git diff --name-only | grep -Ev "dir/")
```

and using

```
git mydiff
```

worked as expected and thus solved my problem. However, I wanted to use Method 2.

**Method 2.**

Adding to **.gitattributes**

```
dir/* -diff
```

and then using

```
git diff
```

Produces the output

```
diff --git a/dir/1 b/dir/1
deleted file mode 100644
index 05e9130..0000000
...
```

**Question**
How to suppress this undesired output for all the files in dir/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you see output with your settings is that `dir/* -diff` only marks files in `dir` as binary files, so text diff would not apply to them (see `man 5 gitattributes`).

To suppress any output for files in `dir` you have to define an external diff driver like this:

1. Assign new "silent" (you can choose your name) diff driver:

   ```
   $ cat .gitattributes 
   dir/* diff=silent
   ```
2. Define "silent" diff function:

   ```
   $ tail -n2 .git/config
   [diff "silent"]
       command = "true"
   ```

That should do the trick.

Comment: thank you very much! Great example for me that reading man is the right way to do things. The only thing I didn't get is what means "man **5** gitattributes" - 5th page of man? How can I find it?

Comment: `man 5 gitattributes` explicitly states to use 5th section of manpages. Manpages are grouped into sections by its type: 1 for executable programs or shell commands, 2 for system calls, 3 for library calls, etc. Section 5 contain file formats description. You actually can just type `man gitattributes` and see the same page, but when you have name collisions (i.e. looking manpage for `stat` you should know what you looking for: command (1), syscall (2), library function (3)) you have to specify section to look at. You can tell what section manpage belongs to by looking for number at its header.