# Is it possible to mark specific file or contents of a specific folder as binary in .gitattributes?

Tags: git, gitattributes

In our repo we have a `js` file, that is quite readable, but we do not require any reports about the diffs inside it. It only clutters the screen. So we want it to be considered binary. That's what we do with `*.min.js` and everybody is happy with the results. In `.gitattributes` we got: `*.js text eol=lf` line, now we need to override this for a specific `js` file somehow. I've tried:

```
filename.js binary
path/filename.js binary
```

I even tried to put `.gitattributes` file under `bin/` folder itself (where we keep all compiled files), with such content:

```
* binary
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Should be something simple I guess?

Comment: Did you add and commit your `.gitattributes` file in the bin/ folder?

Comment: Yes, but it kept to show diff for specified js file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **completely** remove some files from `git diff` output, [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14789642/229034) can be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a .gitattributes in the bin folder saying this:

```
*.js binary
```