# How to disable .so file diff in Git local changes in Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio

In Android Studio,I added .so files to VCS, but every time I click on the .so file, it will show the file  diff,which is very slow.How can I disable diff .so files without add .so files to .gitigore?

[image: so file difference showed in Local Changes]

Answer (score 0):

Check first if Ansroid Studio would respect [`.gitattributes` directives](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes).
Since you can [excludes files from diff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1017676/6309) through said directives, add in a `.gitattributes` file:

```
.so -diff
```

Comment: It seems dosen't work. I don't know how to check if Android  Studio would respect .gitattributes directives.

Comment: @GS. Can you try and add, commit and push that .gitattributes, then clone again the same repository in a different folder, and see if an Android Studio session (using that new clone) still have the same issue?